# How come my syllables do get fetched back, but not my word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, I'm able to fetch my syllables the correct way, but somehow I cannot fetch my `word`, but the thing is: I'm fetching my `word` the exact same way as I am doing with my syllables.

```
function getExerciseBlock(i, data) {
    var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
    'id': i,
    'class': 'col-md-6 eBlock well'
    });

    data = data || {
        word: '',
        syllables: ['','','','']
    };

    $(eBlock).append(
        getRemoveBtnExercise(i),
        getAudioBtn(i),
        getWordInput(i, data.word),
        getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[0]),
        getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[1]),
        getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[2]),
        getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[3])
    );
    return eBlock;
}
```

The "loop" that fetches it back:

```
// Below this comment starts the fetching data back, so the moderator can change data
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {

    // Loops through the words and fetches them back to the CMS side.
    var exercise = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

    exercise.forEach((exercise, index) => {
        $('#my_form').append(getExerciseBlock(index, exercise));
            console.log(exercise);
        });
    });
});
```

My JSON looks like below:

```
{
    "main_object": {
        "id": "new",
        "getExerciseTitle": "Example",
        "language": "nl_NL",
        "application": "lettergrepen",
        "main_object": {
            "title": "Example",
            "language": "nl_NL",
            "exercises": [{
                "word": "Example",
                "syllables": [
                    "Example1",
                    "Example2",
                    "",
                    ""
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "dataType": "json"
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Someone asked me to provide these functions:

getWordInput is the function where the `word` should go (when fetched back from my JSON)

```
  function getWordInput(id, cValue) {
  cValue = cValue || '';
 var wInput = $('<input/>', {
'class': 'exerciseGetWordInput_' + id + ' form-group form-control ExerciseGetWordInput word',  
'type': 'text',
'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord['+ exerciseAudioInput +']',
'placeholder': 'Exercise',
'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput',
'required': true
 });
 return wInput;
}
```

getWordPartInput = for the syllables in my JSON file which DO work.

```
// This is the function that creates the syllable inputs.
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
 cValue = cValue || '';
var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
'class': 'form-group form-control syllable syl ' + TT ++,
'type': 'text',
'value': cValue,
'placeholder': 'Syllables',
'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID++ +']'
 });
 return wpInput;
}
```

The bits of code asked for, but to me looks quite useless:

```
function getAudioBtn(id, cValue){
 cValue = cValue || '';
  var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'sound btn btn-primary'
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
 return audioBtn;
}

function getRemoveBtnExercise(target, i){
var RemoveExerciseBtn = $('<a/>', {
  'class': 'btn btn-danger'
 }).on('click', function(){  
 console.log($('.eblock').prop('id'))
    $('#' + target).remove();
}).html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');

return RemoveExerciseBtn;
}
```

This piece of code underneath is an add button that creates the `eBlock` with all the functions when clicked on. This button will be used when the moderator wants to create a whole new exercise for example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var id = 0;
 var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
'class': 'btn btn-success',
'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
  $('#my_form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
  $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select();
 id++;
 exerciseAudioInput++;
}).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

 $('#my_form').append(addOpdracht);
 $('#my_form').append(getExerciseTitle());
});
```

Comment: Do you have a console error message to go with it? What is `getWordInput`()` function? It would also greatly help if you could tidy up your formatting

Comment: Share these code of these functions `getRemoveBtnExercise(i),
  getAudioBtn(i),
  getWordInput(i, data.word),
  getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[0]),
  getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[1]),
  getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[2]),
  getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables[3])` See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I know pretty much for a fact that the getRemoveBtn and getAudioBtn have nothing to do with this. But you ask, I deliver. do bare in mind that it's going to be messy once I provide all the functions.  do I have console.log errors? No. 0.

Comment: @musefan You are correct about the "Tidy up formatting". That's something I will have to work on. apologies.

Comment: Could you whip up a [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem? It's  a bit difficult to follow your code currently. (you can even use it's "tidy" feature to help you format your code in the question!)

Comment: I don't know how to demonstrate the problem with a JSFIDDLE since it needs to fetch data back from a JSON file. But I could make a JSFIDDLE to show you what I mean if that's fine by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing `'value': cValue,` in the `getWordInput()` function. Edit as follows:

```
function getWordInput(id, cValue) {
    cValue = cValue || '';
    var wInput = $('<input/>', {
        'class': 'exerciseGetWordInput_' + id + ' form-group form-control ExerciseGetWordInput word',  
        'type': 'text',
        'value': cValue,
        'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord['+ exerciseAudioInput +']',
        'placeholder': 'Exercise',
        'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput',
        'required': true
 });
 return wInput;
}
```

Comment: I would give u a 1000 thumbs up if I could. You nailed it right away. Thank you VERY much. I cannot "upvote" ur comment since I need 15 rep atleast, but still. I appreciate it a lot

Comment: When you run into this kind of problem, just print as much as you can into the console. Debug as much as possible, you will find the issue pretty easily ;)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.